# In PgAdmin 4 Utility not found

Tags: sql, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

**Please help me resolve this error**

> 'C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\pgAdmin 4\runtime\pg_restore.exe' file not found. Please correct the Binary Path in the Preferences dialog

[image: 1]

Comment: Not an answer to my question, but since this page came up when I was looking, I'll stick this here:
If your error when validating the binary path is "shell-init: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: No such file or directory could not identify current directory: No such file or directory (PostgreSQL) 14.2" on a mac with homebrew, you need to shut down and re-open the app, as homebrew moved the directory when updating the app.

Comment: This helped me resolve an error referencing liblz4.dll not being found and exit code 3221225781 .  I'm mentioning both in this comment in hopes that search engines may see them and help others find this post.

Answer (score 63):

Please set binary path by using steps mention in below screenshot.
[image]

Comment: Make sure you set the path for the *PostgreSQL Binary Path*, not the *EDB Advanced Server Binary Path*

Comment: What is in the screenshot is: File -> Preferences -> Paths -> Binary paths -> PosgreSQL Binary Path. Then match the version to whichever are installed and pick one to be the default. If only one is installed, and it is the one that is packaged for the OS, then it may be as simple as getting the version from `psql --version` and setting the path to `/usr/bin`.

Answer (score 6):

Configure pgAdmin->Paths->Binary paths and set

> "PostgreSQL Binary Path" to

your postgres installation folder/bin.

There you should find all the executables such as (pg_dump.exe, pg_restore.exe...etc)